# Как получить доступ к response в fetch?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

Типичный пример по fetch, которым полон гугл (конкретно этот с хабра):

```
fetch('http://some-site.com/cors-enabled/some.json', {mode: 'cors'})  
  .then(function(response) {  
    return response.text();  
  })  
  .then(function(text) {  
    console.log('Request successful', text);  
  })  
  .catch(function(error) {  
    log('Request failed', error)  
  });
```

Но вот как получить доступ к `response` из второго `then`?

Я, конечно, могу перед `return response.text()` просто запихнуть его в какую-то внешнюю переменную, но это в общем случае выглядит как-то ненадёжно, потому что асинхронщина, глупый юзер два раза кнопку нажмёт, например, и в переменной по фантастическому везению окажется какой-нибудь другой `response` другого запроса.

Хотелось бы просто передать его дальше в функцию, и, подозреваю, надо как-то городить свои промисы, но я ещё недостаточно крут, чтоб нагородить их самостоятельно, боюсь глупостей натворить.

Comment: А если передать return как объект просто?

Comment: @dimaua или я чего-то не понял, или не, `response.text()` это промис и его результат мне тоже надо как-то получить

Comment: То есть return {text:response.text(), response:response} не сработает ?

Comment: @dimaua нет, я так результат промиса не получу

Comment: так, а зачем во втором then response?

Comment: @Grundy там ссылка, статус, заголовки и прочая нужная мне мета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу выбрать необходимые поля и дождаться их выполнения всех вместе с помощью [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (если какой-то из элементов массива не *Promise*, он будет автоматически преобразован в него с помощью `Promise.resolve`):

```
fetch('http://some-site.com/cors-enabled/some.json', {mode: 'cors'})  
  .then(function(response) {  
    return Promise.all([response.text(), /*что-то еще*/, /* что-то еще*/]);  
  })  
  .then(function(array) {  
    var text = array[0];
    var /*что-то еще*/ = array[1];
    var /* что-то еще*/ = array[2];
    console.log('Request successful', text);  
  })  
  .catch(function(error) {  
    log('Request failed', error)  
  });
```

Либо поступить еще проще: сохранить нужный Promise, и делать ответвления уже от него

```
var fetchResult = fetch('http://some-site.com/cors-enabled/some.json', {mode: 'cors'});

fetchResult.then(function(response) {  
    return response.text();  
}).then(function(text) {  
    console.log('Request successful', text);  
}); 

fetchResult.then(function(response) {  
    return response.json();  
}).then(function(json) {  
    console.log('Request successful', json);  
});
```

Comment: А вот это выглядит неплохо. Но так как я за несколько месяцев уже забыл, зачем конкретно оно мне было надо, прокомментирую/отмечу ответ позже)

Comment: Хм, а ведь сам `response` уже не промис, а вполне готовая переменная и ждать там ничего не надо, я же не могу просто так взять и запихнуть её вместо `/* что-то еще */`?

Comment: @andreymal, не понял вопроса

Comment: Что мне писать вместо `/* что-то еще */`, чтобы во втором then получить доступ к response?

Comment: @andreymal, так и писать `response`

Comment: А, оно так даже работает, ну хорошо)

Comment: @andreymal, [В результате выполнения всех перечисленных обещаний формируется массив, который будет передан общему обещанию, возвращаемому методом `Promise.all(iterable)`. Данный массив будет содержать значения, передаваемые перечисляемыми обещаниеми с помощью метода resolve(value). **Если какой-либо элемент перечисляемого объекта не является обещанием, то он будет преобразован с помощью метода `Promise.resolve`**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: @andreymal, но вообще идея была в том, чтобы не `response` передавать, а выбрать из него сразу все что надо

Comment: Ага, но если вдруг понадобится сразу и статус, и ссылку, и прочую дребедень, то может оказаться проще передать сам response

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41856/discussion-between-grundy-and-andreymal).